# Pass column value as Date Part argument

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to generate a string array of weekdays and use it find how many times each day appears in a month

I am using standard sql on BigQuery

My query would look like

```
with weeks as (select array['SUNDAY','MONDAY','TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY','THURSDAY','FRIDAY','SATURDAY'] as wk)
select DATE_DIFF('2019-01-31','2019-01-01',WEEK(wk)) AS week_weekday_diff 
from weeks, unnest(wk) as wk
```

The query however fails with the error `A valid date part argument for WEEK is required, but found wk`. wk is a column value having the Days of Week, `WEEK` is a Functions which expects a literal `DAYOFWEEK`. Is there a way i pass the column value as arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> error "A valid date part argument for WEEK is required, but found wk"

```
WEEK(<WEEKDAY>): Valid values for WEEKDAY are literal SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, and SATURDAY.
```

> ... Is there a way i pass the column value as arguments?

If you wish - you can submit feature request at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0

> find how many times each day appears in a month

To get your expected result and overcome above "issue" you can approach task from opposite angle - just extract weekdays positions and then do needed stats as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH weekdays AS (SELECT ['SUNDAY','MONDAY','TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY','THURSDAY','FRIDAY','SATURDAY'] AS wk)
SELECT wk[ORDINAL(pos)] weekday, COUNT(1) cnt
FROM weekdays, 
  UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2019-01-01','2019-01-31')) day, 
  UNNEST([EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM day)]) pos
GROUP BY pos, weekday
ORDER BY pos
```

with result

```
Row weekday     cnt  
1   SUNDAY      4    
2   MONDAY      4    
3   TUESDAY     5    
4   WEDNESDAY   5    
5   THURSDAY    5    
6   FRIDAY      4    
7   SATURDAY    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying your query, what I have noticed to be returning an error is:

```
select DATE_DIFF('2019-01-31','2019-01-01',WEEK('WEDNESDAY')) AS week_weekday_diff;
```

as the function WEEK(< WEEKDAY >) is expecting something like:

```
select DATE_DIFF('2019-01-31','2019-01-01',WEEK(`WEDNESDAY`)) AS week_weekday_diff;
```

OR

```
select DATE_DIFF('2019-01-31','2019-01-01',WEEK(WEDNESDAY)) AS week_weekday_diff;
```

I think that the WEEK(< WEEKDAY >) only accepts the weekdays in the format exposed [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_diff), so no strings should be valid.